# Convert only first worksheet XLSX files to CSV files

Tags: vba, csv

I would like to convert all XLSX files in a certain directory to CSV files. Each resulting CSV file should only contain the first worksheet of the XLSX file and be saved in a subfolder of the directory.
I am using the following script which works fine, except that it saves all worksheets as a separate CSV. I just need the first.

Could someone tell me how to modify the script? I have very little experience with VBA.

```
Sub Loop_Through_Files()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

myExtension = "*.xl??"
myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
myFile = Dir(myPath & "\" & "Input" & "\" & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Open workbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & "\" & "Input" & "\" & myFile)

SaveToDirectory = ActiveWorkbook.Path

For Each WS In x.Worksheets
WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & Left(x.Name, InStr(x.Name, ".") - 1) & "_" & WS.Name, xlCSV
Next


x.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Get next file name
myFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: if you only want the first sheet, then either DON'T use a `for` loop, or do something like `for (...) { write sheet; break  }`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `for` loop with this:

```
WS = x.Sheets(1)
WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & Left(x.Name, InStr(x.Name, ".") - 1) & "_" & WS.Name, xlCSV
```